# Double infinite summation

Tags: sequences-and-series

While analyzing performance of a cooperative system over Nakagami-m fading channel, I get the following double infinite summation:

$\sum\limits_{m = 0}^\infty  {\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{\left( {m + n + 2} \right)!}}{{\left( {m + 1} \right)!\left( {n + 1} \right)!}}{x^m}{y^n}} }$

I have spent sometime on it but I cannot get a closed-form solution.
Can you please give me some hints how to solve it?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$
\frac{(m+n+2)!}{(m+1)!(n+1)!} = \binom{m+n+2}{m+1}
$$
and recall
$$
(x+y)^N = \sum_{m+n=N} \binom{N}{m}x^my^n
$$

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.
However, I'm still unclear how to go further. ^^
Can you please explain in more detail?
Thank you very much.